# Why my TFT screen takes time to fill screen?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am using WB-7 TFT LCD Module Rev2.2 in 8-bit mode with MCU dsPIC33EP512MU810 cloicking at 80 MHz. The LCD module is 7-inch 800x480 display with SSD1963 controller.

I am totally new to using LCD screens with microcontrollers. Whenever I execute the command `TFT_Fill_Screen(CL_Black)`, the screen takes 2-3 seconds to change each line to black.

Furthermore, if I change this colour to blue, now instead of blue, the screen starts changing to red color!

I am using [MikroC Pro for dsPIC library TFT Display](http://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/tft_library.htm).

My question is:

1. On what does the speed of screen loading depends upon?
2. Why if I change my fill-screen colour, a new unknown color starts appearing on screen?
3. I want to keep on using the screen in 8-bit mode (not 16). Is there any way I can speed things up?

My code is as following:

```
// TFT display connections
char TFT_DataPort at LATD;
sbit TFT_WR at LATE1_bit;
sbit TFT_RD at LATE0_bit;
sbit TFT_CS at LATG3_bit;
sbit TFT_RS at LATH6_bit;
sbit TFT_RST at LATH4_bit;

char TFT_DataPort_Direction at TRISD;
sbit TFT_WR_Direction : at TRISE1_bit;
sbit TFT_RD_Direction at TRISE0_bit;
sbit TFT_CS_Direction at TRISG3_bit;
sbit TFT_RS_Direction at TRISH6_bit;
sbit TFT_RST_Direction at TRISH4_bit;
// End of TFT display connections

void main() {

    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 0;
    PLLFBD = 38;
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0;

    ANSELE = 0xFF;
    ANSELD = 0xFF;
    ANSELG = 0xFF;
    ANSELH = 0xFF;

    // Initialize 240x320 TFT display
    TFT_Init_SSD1963_8bit(800,480);

    TFT_Fill_Screen(CL_BLACK);

}
```

Comment: 1) It depends, at least, on the speed you are sending data to controller. 2) Probably your RGB map is wrong: HW or SW. 3) Change micro speed? Change Micro? Too broad...

Comment: If you use GPIO to implement the bus protocol then  the time seems right. You see wrong color is because your clock pin has an extra edge and cause the image to be shifted by 1/3 of a pixel each frame.

Comment: This is not complete source code. Could you please share *all* of your source code? If it's large, please provide a link to source. In particular, I'm interested in your clock setup, and SPI initialization.

Comment: Check the datasheet timing characteristics of the display. Then check if there's a write that requires to set address once with auto increment. Then keep writing bytes. Check if the fill function uses this mode and check if there's any delay used. If there's headroom in timing/delay, decrease the delays. Also check what display mode and rgb color mode is used. Does the fill function adjust to the correct mode?